# slow mozilla firefox build

Tags: firefox, build, mozilla

I'm having a problem trying to build mozilla firefox. Despite the fact that my system is quite decent (i5 processor, 16 gb ram, ssd) , the build is very slow. I've used mk_add_options MOZ_MAKE_FLAGS="-j4" option in the mozconfig but my CPU is still at 1-2% of usage. 
Is there something that I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

The initial build can take from 10 minutes to more than an hour, depending on the OS, the build machine specs, and the build configuration.

- Has your build finished at all? What do you call "slow"?
- What OS are you building on? Windows, for example, is much slower to build.
- What version of Firefox are you building (m-c tip? an old version?)
- What's your build configuration (mozconfig)? Are you doing a debug or a release build? Any non-standard options? Did you try [artifact builds](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Developer_guide/Build_Instructions/Artifact_builds)?
- Paste the build log, in particular it prints how much resources it took to build just before the end of the build.
- Do you have A/V or other system software? Did you instruct it to ignore the objdir?